# Force diff/vimdiff to adjust line comparison

Tags: unix, vim, diff, vimdiff

I'm comparing a couple files for differences using `vimdiff`. In this case, one file has 11 lines of comments describing the file whereas the other has no comment lines. I was surprised that `vimdiff` (rather, the underlying 'diff' ) did not accurately assign which lines to compare, so every line is different. In this case, line 12 from the first file should be compared to line 1 from the second.

**Question**: Is there a way to adjust which lines `vimdiff` (or the underlying `diff`) compares (e.g., shift down by 12), without modifying the files?

Really appreciate your help.

Here are initial lines from the files:

**File 1 (includes comments)**

```
# This table shows the intersection of dark by MAPQ regions by a gene annotation gff3, showing where dark by MAPQ regions fall within gene body
# chrom : Chromosome of dark by MAPQ region
# region_start : start position of dark by MAPQ region within gene-body element
# region_end : end position of dark by MAPQ region within gene-body element
# gene_body_id : ID of gene body element that contains this dark by MAPQ region
# region_type : genebody element type (e.g. exon, intron, UTR, etc.)
# biotype : GENCODE biotype of gene that contains this dark by MAPQ reigon
# gene_body_chrom : Chromosome of the genebody element
# gene_body_start : start position of the genebody element
# gene_body_end : end position of the genebody element
#chrom  start   end gene_body_id    region_type biotype gene_body_chrom gene_body_start gene_body_end
1   11869   12227   DDX11L1_1   exon    transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  1   11869   12227
1   12228   12611   DDX11L1_intron_1    intron  transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  1   12228   12611
1   12612   12721   DDX11L1_2   exon    transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  1   12612   12721
1   12722   12751   DDX11L1_intron_2    intron  transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  1   12722   12973
1   12861   12973   DDX11L1_intron_2    intron  transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  1   12722   12973
1   13191   13219   DDX11L1_intron_3    intron  transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  1   13053   13219
```

**File 2 (does not include comments)**

```
chr1    11869   12227   DDX11L1_1   exon    transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  chr1    11869   12227
chr1    12228   12611   DDX11L1_intron_1    intron  transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  chr1    12228   12611
chr1    12612   12721   DDX11L1_2   exon    transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  chr1    12612   12721
chr1    12722   12752   DDX11L1_intron_2    intron  transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  chr1    12722   12973
chr1    12861   12973   DDX11L1_intron_2    intron  transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  chr1    12722   12973
chr1    13191   13219   DDX11L1_intron_3    intron  transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  chr1    13053   13219
```

**VimDiff result**
[image: Line 12 from file 1 should be compared to line 1 from file 2]

Comment: Actually, after seeing the results from my answer (below), I suspect the reason `vimdiff`/`diff` didn't compare the "right" lines is because all lines really are different from the first character (i.e., `1` vs. `chr1`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have the same problem so I developed https://github.com/rickhowe/spotdiff.vim. You have to specify the line range but can partially compare any line between 2 files or even in a single file. You can also select visual area and text object to compare.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution for this situation using `tail` but would appreciate solutions where I can modify it directly in `vimdiff`.

```
# Skip the first 12 lines from file_1
vimdiff <(tail -n +12 file_1) file_2
```